# Excel: Save only filtered data model for Power Pivot and remove queries and connections

Tags: excel, powerquery, powerpivot, datamodel

Good day,

This question has been asked on Stack Overflow but solutions are mostly for smaller datasets and the bigger ones don't have solutions yet (Sorry if  missed it, but I couldn't find any on here or other sites).

I'm extracting a file with Analyse in Excel from the Companies Power BI database Online. This gives me access to all the pivot tables and measures.

I have to build a report where the vendor can be selected, thus filters all the data to only include the vendor's data in pivot tables with slicers. This is easy enough I can do that with a filter or slicer in Power Pivot.
A copy of this file needs to be saved so that there are no connections or queries and only includes the vendor's data, since it will be sent to the client and for security no access to other vendor's data or the whole database are allowed. The original file will be refreshed every week and multiple vendors will be selected to create a report for each.

**Is there a way to only save the filtered data model?**

- Cannot load the pivot into a normal table after it's been filtered and then pull it in with power query again, because the are over a million rows which Excel tables don't allow.
- Cannot make a copy of the pivot tables or reference them in a separate workbook because that pulls in all pivot tables and connections and if I delete connections it removes the pivot table
- Someone suggestion using DAX studio to save to a csv and then pull it into a new workbook. This is not ideal, since it needs to be done on a weekly basis for multiple vendors; and from what I read DAX studio csv can only contain 30,000 rows max anyway.

Surely there must be a way of doing this in Excel?
Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is your aim to create a point in time static report. i.e. when you send it out, the pivot tables will just present static data and can no longer be manipulated. If so, you can just delete the connection under Queries and Connections and in the pivot table settings, make sure to check not to refresh on file open. Slicers will obviously no longer work but the static data will remain in place.

If you want to send the filtered file and allow the end user to manipulate pivot tables within their filter without seeing other vendor's data, you would need to use RLS.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @David. They will need to be able to use slicers so first option of deleting connections won't work unfortunately. Only way I can add the slicers is by having a data model. I'll ask the Database developers to look into RLS thanks.

Comment: FYI, RLS is implemented in the PowerBI data model. Don't forget to mark as solved if your question is answered.